# Установка Windows 10 на старый компьютер

Tags: windows, windows-10

У меня есть ноутбук со следующими хар-ками: процессор Intel Core 2 Duo, 1 GB RAM, 20 GB диск C и ~70 GB диск D (я так понимаю, это два раздела на одном HDD диске), графика встроенная. Сейчас стоит Windows XP SP3.  Стоит ли ставить Windows 10? Меня беспокоит то, что он впртык подходит под минимальные тех. требования, не будет ли Win10 лагать на нем?

Comment: Оперативки мало, 4Gb примерно нужно, скорее всего будет лагать. Хотя попробуйте установить)

Comment: Простите, но зачем?

Comment: У меня на старом ноуте, чуть более мощном, чем ваш, стояла восьмёрка. Она сама пыталась обновиться до десятки, но выдавала сообщение, что видюха не подходит, слабовата.

Comment: Для каких целей будет использоваться комп?

Answer (score 0):

Если процессор не соответствует спецификации, то W10 просто не установится сколько его не разгоняй(быстро едущий "жигуль" останется быстро едущим "жигулём", в Мерседес волшебно он не превращается)

[Вместо тысячи слов, официальный источник.](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=822783)
Прежде чем устанавливать программа проверит на соответствие требованиям Win 10, а отказаться от установки можно в любой момент..
может и до установки дело не дойдёт и вопросов не будет